# production.ERROR: could not find driver

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

Когда я пытаюсь удалить файлы из панели администратора на самом сайте, я получаю ошибку в консоли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В журналах сервера Ubuntu 18.04 говорит, что это ошибка

```
[2021-04-25 17:43:40] production.ERROR: could not find driver {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 0): could not find driver at /home/admin/web/site/public_html/vendor/teamtnt/tntsearch/src/Indexer/TNTIndexer.php:181)
```

Вот строка, о которой написано в журналах

```
/**
 * @param string $indexName
 *
 * @return TNTIndexer
 */
public function createIndex($indexName)
{
    $this->indexName = $indexName;

    if (file_exists($this->config['storage'].$indexName)) {
        unlink($this->config['storage'].$indexName);
    }
```

> //Вот эта строка, на которой дается ошибка
> $this->index = new PDO('sqlite:'.$this->config['storage'].$indexName);

```
    $this->index = new PDO('sqlite:'.$this->config['storage'].$indexName); 

    $this->index->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $this->index->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wordlist (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                term TEXT UNIQUE COLLATE nocase,
                num_hits INTEGER,
                num_docs INTEGER)");

    $this->index->exec("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 'main'.'index' ON wordlist ('term');");

    $this->index->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS doclist (
                term_id INTEGER,
                doc_id INTEGER,
                hit_count INTEGER)");

    $this->index->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fields (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                name TEXT)");

    $this->index->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hitlist (
                term_id INTEGER,
                doc_id INTEGER,
                field_id INTEGER,
                position INTEGER,
                hit_count INTEGER)");

    $this->index->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info (
                key TEXT,
                value INTEGER)");

    $this->index->exec("INSERT INTO info ( 'key', 'value') values ( 'total_documents', 0)");

    $this->index->exec("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS 'main'.'term_id_index' ON doclist ('term_id' COLLATE BINARY);");
    $this->index->exec("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS 'main'.'doc_id_index' ON doclist ('doc_id');");

    if (!$this->dbh) {
        $connector = $this->createConnector($this->config);
        $this->dbh = $connector->connect($this->config);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Что не так на сервере настроено или что не установлено пожалуйста скажите мне весь интернет искал не нашел решения

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Comment: Перевел на русский язык

Comment: @Boiko, в `php.ini` раскомментирована строка `extension=pdo_sqlite.so` (для Windows - `extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`) ?